# Parallel package is not available in R 3.3.1 (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: r, multiprocessing, ubuntu-14.04

I'm doing some heavy work with my computer. I'd like R used the 4 processors . But, used one at a time. I think the parallel package can be useful, but is not available. What I can do?

When I try to install the following appears

```
> install.packages("parallel")
Installing package into ‘/home/hector/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3’
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘parallel’ is not available (for R version 3.3.1)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘parallel’ is a base package, and should not be updated
```

Here is my `sessionInfo`:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

locale:
  [1] LC_CTYPE=es_CL.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=es_CL.UTF-8       
  [4] LC_COLLATE=es_CL.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=es_CL.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=es_CL.UTF-8   
  [7] LC_PAPER=es_CL.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
  [10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=es_CL.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
  [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] tools_3.3.1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some packages are coming with R as recommended packages, like `parallel`, `compiler` and `mgcv`. You don't need to install or update them; when you upgrade your R version, they will be upgraded, too, if new package release is available.

These packages are not loaded on R start-up; but you can get them immediately by

```
library(parallel)
library(compiler)
library(mgcv)
```

an so on.